# Как реализовать добавление в словарь?

Tags: python, словари

В первой строке записывается число k(сколько раз будет выполняться запрос строчек в цикле). Далее в каждой строке записывается слово и сразу же через пробел идет описание к этому слову, так вот в чем вопрос, как это слово добавить в качестве ключа в словарь, а все что идет в этой же строке через пробел после этого ключа записать в словарь в value

попытался сделать так, но не получается(почему то задаю значение 2 на входе, а ввожу 4 строки и в словарь естественно идет не первое слово строки, а вся строка и в значение вторая строка)

```
arr = {}
for i in range(int(input())):
  k, v = input(), input()  
  arr[k] = v
print(arr)
```

например в итоге это должно выглядеть так:

```
1
слово описание к этому слову
arr = {"слово": "Описание к этому слову", ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
arr = {}

for i in range(int(input())):
    k, v = input().split(' ', 1)
    arr[k] = v

print(arr)
```

- input() - ожидает ввод с клавиатуры и возвращает строку;
- .split(' ', 1) - разбивает по первому пробелу и возвращает список;
- k, v - распаковывает список в две переменные

У вас же `k, v = input(), input()` делает ровно то, что вы описали: принимает две строки и первую устанавливает, как ключ, вторую - значением словаря...